# How to prevent specific method calls to bitcoin node

Tags: json-rpc, nodes

I have setup a bitcoin node and can access RPC methods via curl or bitcoin-cli.

Now I don't want to share the node with multiple parties and in such case, I want to restict some functions from being executed, like `listwallets`, `getbalance` etc.

**How can I restrict some method calls?**

In Ethereum we have different `rpcapi` and we can remove personal if we don't want others to play around with it unsafely.

My first guess will be to wrap the wallet functionalities in an application server and allow users to access the blockchain node via that application server and hence we can put any restrictions we want. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin-core has no built-in mechanisms for restricting access to the API.

For your goals, you need to use a proxy between the user and the node.

For example, https://github.com/rsksmart/rskj/wiki/Nginx-Proxy-Server-for-JSONRPC-Calls